# Denying load of chrome extension

Tags: php, google-chrome-extension

May be such question has been asked number of times, and i refered those also but i am not able to understand those answers properly.

So i am posting here my question.

At the time of running php website, i am getting this error in inspect element:

```
Denying load of chrome extension://kdidombaedgpfiiedeimiebkmbilgmlc/css/jquery_ui/images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png. Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key in order to be loaded by pages outside the extension.
Failed to load resource
```

I am not getting why this error is coming? And its first time when i am having such error.

Please help me out in solving this error in detail as it is totally new to me.

Comment: This here is not the Google Chrome support website. You find it here: https://support.google.com/chrome/

Answer (score 1):

> I am not getting why this error is coming?

Google Chrome gives you the exact error description. If the wording is too technical for you to understand, please [contact the software vendor](http://www.google.com/contact/) for your support options or try to locate it in the source-code of the application with a string-search and read and understand the code that leads to the error.

Alternatively run the software with debugging symbols enabled and place a breakpoint at that place. Then debug it.

> And its first time when i am having such error.

Yes you probably personally have this error the first time, however having an error message here is a good sign that there is more reference available.

Imagine the application would just crash because some error condition would not have been caught. That would be much more hard to deal with.